# Change Javascript in a Firefox extension overlay

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, dom-events, xul

I wrote an extension for Firefox with an overlay.

When I click on the principal button, the extension loads `entconnect.entImmediat`, but when I click on "Changez vos identifiants", the extension loads `entconnect.openLogs` AND `entconnect.entImmediat`. How can I do for just load entconnect.openLogs when I click on "Changez vos identifiants"?
This is the code of my overlay :

```xml
<overlay id="entconnect-overlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<script src="chrome://entconnect/content/entconnect.js"/>
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
    <toolbarbutton class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional" id="entconnect-addbar" label="Allez sur votre ENT" type="menu-button" oncommand="entconnect.entImmediat();">
        <menupopup>
            <menuitem label="Changez vos identifiants" oncommand="entconnect.openLogs();"/>
        </menupopup>                             
    </toolbarbutton>
</toolbarpalette>
</overlay>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command event bubbles up meaning that it will be received by event handlers further up in the DOM hierarchy. You can [prevent the event from bubbling further up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation) if you already handled it:

```
oncommand="entconnect.openLogs();event.stopPropagation();"
```

Or you can look at the [event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.target):

```
oncommand="if (event.target.localName != 'menuitem') entconnect.entImmediat();"
```

Or you can simply process only the events that were [triggered at the current element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.eventPhase):

```
oncommand="if (event.eventPhase == event.AT_TARGET) entconnect.entImmediat();"
```

Comment: @user1673772: Feel free to accept the question if it helped: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask